# Indexing nested list with another list

Tags: list-manipulation, index

So I'm wanting to index the sublists within a list using another list. 
So I have

```
x = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
```

And I want the 2nd term of the first sublist, 1st term of the 2nd sublist, 3rd term of the 3rd sublist, i.e. I want output {2,4,9} or {{2},{4},{9}}

This is a simple example of a generalised problem, where x might be several thousand elements long with each element being a list with thousands of elements, and I might want to use a function like 'Take' instead of indexing, e.g. I might want to take the first 2 terms of the first list, the first term of the second list and the first 3 terms of the 3rd list to get the output {{1,2},{4},{7,8,9}}.

I have discovered the Thread function, which gives the following:

```
In[386]:= Thread[g[{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 3}]]
Out[386]= {g[1, 2], g[2, 1], g[3, 3]}
```

Therefore, I figured if I define *f* as follows

```
f[p_, q_] := x[[p, q]];
```

I would be able to write

```
Thread[f[{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 3}]]
```

And return the value obtained by evaluating

```
{f[1, 2], f[2, 1], f[3, 3]}
```

Which is {2,4,9} as I require.

Indeed, Mathematica gives

```
In[384]:= {f[1, 2], f[2, 1], f[3, 3]}
Out[384]= {2, 4, 9}
```

But

```
In[387]:= Thread[f[{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 3}]]
Out[387]= {{2, 5, 8}, {1, 4, 7}, {3, 6, 9}}
```

Why is this happening? Why doesn't my method work? Is there a better way?

Many thanks,

H

Comment: Depth of your list is not 3. So f [1,2,3]  doesn't make sense

Comment: Apply is probably not what you want here, but nevertheless: `x[[##]] & @@@ Transpose[{Range@Length@x, {;; 2, 1, 1 ;;}}]` -> {{1, 2}, 4, {7, 8, 9}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Why is this happening?***

[Thread >> Possible Issues](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thread.html):

> ***Thread** evaluates the whole expression before threading.*
>   ***MapThread** takes the function and its arguments separately.*

So you can wrap the first argument of `Thread` with `Unevaluated` to prevent evaluation before threading and get the desired result:

```
Thread[Unevaluated@f[{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 3}]]
```

> {2, 4, 9}

Also

```
MapThread[f, {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 3}}]
Inner[f, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 3}, List]
MapIndexed[x[[#2[[1]], #]] &, {2, 1, 3}]
f @@@ Thread[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 3}}]
f @@@ Transpose[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 3}}]
Extract[x, MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, {2, 1, 3}]]
```

> {2, 4, 9}

Answer (score 2):

Since

```
f[{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 3}]
```

> {{2, 1, 3}, {5, 4, 6}, {8, 7, 9}}

You get

```
Thread[{{2, 1, 3}, {5, 4, 6}, {8, 7, 9}}]
```

> {{2, 5, 8}, {1, 4, 7}, {3, 6, 9}}

Instead you could use `MapThread` or `Diagonal`

```
Diagonal[Transpose[x][[{2, 1, 3}]]]    (* or Diagonal[x[[All, {2, 1, 3}]]] *)
MapThread[#[[#2]] &, {x, {2, 1, 3}}]
MapThread[#[[;; #2]] &, {x, {2, 1, 3}}]
```

> {2, 4, 9}
>   {2, 4, 9}
>   {{1, 2}, {4}, {7, 8, 9}}